# How can I set a custom Template for djangocms-blog?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-cms

I have a djangocms based website and now I would like to have an app which will help with a small blog section.

Now, I have successfully integrate [djangocms-blog](https://github.com/nephila/djangocms-blog) in my website, but when I am trying to see a post, the template (a custom template made by me) is not rendered and the post (made from blog admin) is just thrown on the page.

Can anybody help me out with this issue ? Would you like any additional info in order to help me out with this ?

My template looks like this:

```html
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load cms_tags %}

{% block title %}{% page_attribute "page_title" %}{% endblock title %}

{% block content %}

    <div class="spacer"></div>
    <div class="page-header page-header-blog-post-1 white">
        <div class="page-header-container container">
            <div class="page-header-content">
                <h1 class="heading">BLOG</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


    <div class="blog-container blog-single container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8 blog-content margin-bottom-70 clearfix">
                {% placeholder banner_leaderboard_top %}
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8 blog-content margin-bottom-70 clearfix">
                <article id="post-1" class="post-1 post format-standard">
                    <header class="entry-header">
                        <div class="post-thumbnail-area">
                            {% placeholder "post_header_image" or %}
                            <img src="/static/img/onepage-slide9.jpg" alt="image_blog"/>
                            {% endplaceholder %}
                        </div>
                    </header>
                    <div class="entry-content">
                        <div class="entry-title blog-info">
                            <h1 class="heading">{% placeholder "post_header_title" or %}POST_TITLE{% endplaceholder %}</h1>
                        </div>
                        {% placeholder "POST_BODY" or %}POST_BODY{% endplaceholder %}
                    </div>
                    <footer class="entry-footer">
                        <div class="entry-description">
                            <h6 class="post-date-classic">{% placeholder "post_date" or %}POST_DATE{% endplaceholder %}</h6>
                        </div>
                    </footer>
                </article>
                <div class="post-additional">
                    <script type="text/javascript">
                        // Popup window code
                        function newPopup(url) {
                            popupWindow = window.open(
                                    url, 'popUpWindow', 'height=700,width=800,left=10,top=10,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,toolbar=yes,menubar=no,location=no,directories=no,status=yes')
                        }
                    </script>
                    <ul class="post-share list-inline">
                        <li><a href="JavaScript:newPopup('https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u='+window.location.href)"><i
                                class="icon ion-social-facebook"></i></a></li>
                        <li><a href="JavaScript:newPopup('http://twitter.com/home/?status=Nice blog post - '+window.location.href);"><i
                                class="icon ion-social-twitter"></i></a></li>
                        <li><a href="JavaScript:newPopup('https://plus.google.com/share?url='+window.location.href); "><i
                                class="icon ion-social-googleplus"></i></a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <div class="post-navigation nav-links">
                        <ul class="post-controls list-inline">
                            <li>
                                {% placeholder "prev_post" or %}
                                <a class="post-prev" href="#"><i class="icon ion-ios7-arrow-thin-left"></i></a></li>
                                {% endplaceholder %}
                            <li>
                                {% placeholder "next_post" or %}
                                <a class="post-next" href="#"><i class="icon ion-ios7-arrow-thin-right"></i></a></li>
                                {% endplaceholder %}
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="author-bio">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="author-avatar col-xs-4 col-sm-3 col-md-3 visible-desktop">
                            {% placeholder "author_img" or %}
                            <img src="/static/img/image-8.jpg" alt="image_blog"></div>
                            {% endplaceholder %}
                        <div class="author-details white col-md-9">
                            <h3>{% placeholder "author_name" or %}AUTHOR_NAME{% endplaceholder %}</h3>
                            <p>{% placeholder "author_body" or %}AUTHOR_BODY{% endplaceholder %}</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                {% placeholder banner_leaderboard_bottom %}
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="sidebar">

                    <aside id="recent-posts-2" class="widget widget_recent_entries">
                        <div class="widget-title">
                            <h5 class="heading">RECENT POSTS</h5>

                            <div class="fancy-line-small"></div>
                        </div>
                            {% placeholder "post_recent" or %}
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="#">Recent blog post</a></li>
                            </ul>
                            {% endplaceholder %}
                    </aside>

                {% placeholder banner_square_right %}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Some image with administration of djangocms-blog:

[image: Screenshot of administration of django-cms blog.]

So, I'd like the Title from Blog admin to be applied on my template instead of `<h1 class="heading">BLOG</h1>` and so on for `date` , `category` and so on

Answer (score 4):

If you want to override a template used by an app that you've installed you simply need to mimic the same template path in your template directory.

The CMS blog templates can be found [here](https://github.com/nephila/djangocms-blog/tree/develop/djangocms_blog/templates/djangocms_blog).

So to override the CMS blog templates you should decide which template needs to be overridden, in this case it sounds like `post_detail.html` because you're concerned with how a post displays.

So in your project you need to create something like; `myproj/templates/djangocms_blog/post_detail.html`

Then the system will load that one instead of the `post_detail.html` from the site-packages folder.

Comment: Additionally, you can add a template prefix other than `djangocms_blog` in the blog's config. This allows you to have different templates for different blogs on your site.